# What is the difference between “Voy a ir al cine” and Voy al cine”?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado, objetos-indirectos

What is the right sentence? Or are they both used? I want to know the exact meaning of the two sentences. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are right, but they are used in different situations:

1. **Voy a ir al cine**: used when you have the plan of going to the cinema but it is something you are going to do in the future.

*Example*:

- Esta tarde hemos quedado para ir a tomar algo al centro del pueblo, ¿te apuntas?
- No, ya lo siento, voy a ir al cine a ver una película.

---

2. **Voy al cine**: used when you want to explain a routine or something you are doing right now.

*Example 1*:

- Hace mucho que no nos vemos, ¿dónde te metes los fines de semana?
- Los sábados voy al cine y los domingos suelo ir al monte con mi hermano.

*Example 2*:

- ¡Hasta luego Emilio! ¿Dónde vas?
- Voy al cine, luego cuando termine la película te llamo y quedamos un rato.

Comment: No necesariamente voy es ‘right now’. Puede ser un evento arreglado que ocurrirá dentro de pronto.

Answer (score 1):

Hay que considerara dos situaciones:

**Si el evento acontece regularmente**: Sólo vale ‘voy al cine’, seguido del adverbio correspondiente claro está.

**Si es para referir a un evento futuro**: Ambas frases son casi equivalentes e intercambiables la gran mayoría de las veces. Lo que define cuándo se emplea una u otra es **la CER-TE-ZA del evento**, y no en qué momento acontece.

> —Cariño, **voy a ir al cine mañana**. Nos podemos ver el domingo. Te parece bien?
> —No hay problema
> —De acuerdo, entonces **voy al cine mañana**. *Nos vemos* el domingo. (atenti al uso del presente para referir al futuro)

Ambas expresiones se usan cuando el evento es muy probable. Pero la primera pide algo de confirmación y la segunda ya lo da por asentado que así será. En cambio, decir por ejemplo ‘iré al cine’ ya suena a algo mucho más dudoso que las dos construcciones de tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

They have a different meaning:

1. I'm going to go to the cinema (immediate future)
2. I go to the cinema (present)

---

1. Voy a ir al cine (futuro inmediato)
2. Voy al cine (presente)

<sub>*More about "futuro inmediato" at [lingolia.com](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/tiempos/futuro-proximo-ir-a#:%7E:text=La%20per%C3%ADfrasis%20ir%20a%20%2B%20infinitivo%20se%20emplea%20en%20espa%C3%B1ol%20para,los%20clasificadores%20y%20las%20carpetas.)*</sub>

Comment: Or even for option 2 "I am going to the cinema" if you are currently in the middle of the journey.

Comment: I go to the cinema is not right here.  I'm going to the cinema [now]= Voy al cine. in this case. Voy al cine todas las semanas. I go to the cinema every week.

Answer (score 0):

In Spanish, for: **I'm going to the cinema** [now] is **Voy al cine.** Verbo: ir

In Spanish, for: **I'm going to go to the cinema** [later or future] is **Voy a ir al cine.** Verbo: voy a + infinito.

In Spanish, for: **I go to the movies often**. [habitual action], **Voy al cine frecuentemente**

Notice how in Spanish, the habitual action and the current/future action both use Voy a  (ir a). Whereas English uses **going to [verb**] for a current/future action.

The English progressive is simple present here in Spanish for the first one.

Another example: I'm playing tennis now. = Voy a jugar al tenis ahora.
I'm going to play tennis.= Voy a ir a jugar al tenis.

Please note: The present simple is used in Spanish for these meanings where English uses the progressive.

COMPARE:
*I play the piano every day. Present simple in English.

*Toco piano todos los dias. Present simple in Spanish.